# A 4x6 grid with adjacent integers with gcd > 1

Tags: mathematics, optimization, number-theory

You are given a 4x6 square grid. Each square of the grid
should be filled with different positive integers.
The gcd (greatest common divisor) of any two adjacent (horizontally or vertically)
squares should be greater than one.

What is the minimum sum of such 24 integers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 366:

> ```
>   9 15  5 20 22 11
>   3 24 10  4 18 33
>  39 12  8 16 14  6
>  13 26  2 28  7 21
> ```

Another solution, with smallest possible maximum entry subject to minimizing the sum:

> ```
>   9 21  7 14 22 11
>   3 12 28  4 18 33
>  24 16  2  8 20 15
>  27  6 26 10 25  5
> ```

If you ignore the sum, the smallest possible maximum entry is smaller by $1$:

> ```
>  28  7 21 18 20  5
>  22 14 12 10 30 25
>  16  4  8  6  3 15
>   2 32 26 24  9 27
> ```

Comment: thanks for your solution. Did you find it using a computer?

Comment: Yes, I solved it via integer linear programming.